# Definition of disc and open ball

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces, definition

I have the following definitions in my notes for arbitrary discs and open balls -

$$D^n = \{x \in \mathbb{R^{n+1}}: ||x|| \le 1\}$$

$$B^n = \{x \in \mathbb{R^{n+1}}: ||x|| < 1\}$$

The $\mathbb{R^{n+1}}$ seems wrong to me...Earlier in my notes I have that $D^2$ is a disc in the plane? So which is correct?

Comment: Not a *sphere*! Spheres are boundaries of discs, $S^{n-1}=\partial D^n$. Usually the superscript denotes the dimension, so $D^n$ is the unit disc in $\mathbb R^n$ and its boundary is $S^{n-1}$, since the boundary of an $n$-disc is of dimension $n-1$.

Comment: I would say $B^n \cong \mathbb{R}^{n+1}$ sounds pretty funny.

Comment: Agreed, this notation seems peculiar. I dare say the lecturer was mistaken, perhaps confusing $S^n$ and $B^n$. Although the notation with $S^n$ sometimes varies, I've never seen it used this way with $B^n$ or $D^n$.

Answer (score 3):

I like to think of that $n$ as the dimension of the underlying manifold (I guess this is also the reason behind this). So you can remember, that $S^n$ is defined as the unit vectors in $\mathbb{R}^{n+1}$, since it is an $n$-dimensional "object". This is also, since it is the boundary of $D^{n+1}$ which is $(n+1)$-dimensional.

Therefore I would definitely say $D^n,B^n \subset \mathbb{R}^n$. This is standard, since they are $n$-dimensional. But be careful: while the dimension is standard, different authors use $D$ and $B$ for different purposes, so $B$ happens to be closed from time to time.